# Stripping parent category but leaving child categories in Wordpress permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I had a site with a url structure like

example.com/news/story-1
example.com/news/local/story-2
example.com/food/tacos/story-3

Now it's been moved to a multisite, with /news/ and /food/ as the site subfolders.

Within those sub-sites, the top level/default category is News or Food, respectively, replacing Uncategorized. So if the permalink is set to `%category%/%postname%/`, the permalink come out as

example.com/news/news/local/story-title
example.com/food/food/tacos/story-title

In order to remove the category that's a duplicate of the site subfolder, I added this to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_category', 10, 3 );
    function remove_parent_category( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
        $permalink_array = explode("/", $permalink);
        $clean_permalink = array_unique($permalink_array);
        $new_permalink = implode("/", $clean_permalink);
        return $new_permalink;
    }
```

This works, giving me back

example.com/news/local/story-2
example.com/food/tacos/story-3

and the ability to navigate categories like

example.com/news/
example.com/news/local/
example.com/news/local/crime/
etc.

However posts that are in the top level category now 404 (which is to be expected) because their url is now

example.com/news/story-1

(which is what I want, but i don't want to set the whole site to just `%postname%/` because you lose the simple tree-link category navigation).

From what I'm gathering I think I need to use either pre_post_link or a rewrite rule to treat those top level posts as if my permalink structure is just `%postname%/` and not `%category%/%postname%/`, but that's where I'm stuck.

What I've tried: I've tried a couple solutions floating around here, among other things I tried a variation on this but the post links with the top category stripped still 404 [wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133587/170714](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133587/170714)

Comment: If the top level categories are already News and Food, why do you need to set a category for those posts?  Meaning, from your description you're saying you essentially have News and Food as duplicate categories.  

In this case you simply don't set a category for those posts and just use the default.  Then set your permalink structure to just use /postname.

Comment: Correct, "News" and "Food" are just convenient names for the default categories — which is why I've been searching around for answers on how to remove "uncategorized" from the permalink, but use category/postname for the other categories — it's essentially the same problem. I don't want to use just /postname because I like having the sub-cat in the permalink, when there is one.

Comment: In this case, I think the best practice is creat endpoint.

Comment: @HoseinShurabi Can you expand on that?

Comment: there are two docs that guide you.

[WP_Rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)
[add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

let me know if you have any question.

Comment: @HoseinShurabi I'll look into it — thank you!